# Set Flex MX ComboBox background color using CSS

Tags: css, flash, apache-flex, combobox, flex-mx

Is there a way using CSS, to set a `mx.controls.ComboBox`'s background color. This would be the background color of each row when the `ComboBox` is clicked (expanded). I've tried `backgroundColor`, `fillColors` and `backgroundGradientColors` without success.

My `ComboBox` is contained within a `FormItem`. I've also tried setting `FormItem`'s `backgroundColor`, `fillColors` and `backgroundGradientColors`. It's not clear to me where `ComboBox` obtains or inherits its list cell background color from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to set is the `dropdownStyleName` to another selector (let's call it '.dropDownStyle') which then sets the `backgroundColor` since the [Combobox is actual made out of 2 parts](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/ComboBox.html).